# Slash missing on laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, class, routes

If I use this option fuction to upload a 12345.jpg

```
Route::post('upload', function(){
      $options['upload_url'] = url('/images/');  
      $options['upload_dir'] = public_path().'/images/';
      $upload_handler = new App\Http\Controllers\UploadController($options);
 });
```

I got the error url  is

```
localhost:8000/public/images12345.jpg  miss the images/
```

if I don't use the function like above

```
Route::post('upload', function(){
      //$options['upload_url'] = url('/images/');  
      //$options['upload_dir'] = public_path().'/images/';
      $upload_handler = new App\Http\Controllers\UploadController();
 });
```

I got the right route (as the controller default)

```
localhost:8000/public/files/12345.jpg
```

UploadController.php

```
 public function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
        $this->response = array();
        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.$this->basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
            'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/',
            'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/',
```

Can anyone can tell me how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the `url()` method, which uses the `UrlGenerator->to()` method. This method calls `trim($path.'/'.$tail, '/')` to cut off trailing slashes ([see code reference](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L200)).

So you might just use `url().'/images/` instead of `url('/images/')`

**or, as a more robust alternative**

add a check in the controller that makes sure there is a trailing slash in place:

```
if (substr($this->options['upload_url'], -1) !== '/') {
    $this->options['upload_url'] .= '/';
}
```